# Mockito http.Client type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito

I'm applying a unit test over a http request in a Flutter application using Mockito.

Code to be tested:

```
@GenerateMocks([http.Client])
void main() {
  late GdprDataSourceImpl dataSource;
  late MockClient mockHttpClient;

  setUp(() {
    mockHttpClient = MockClient();
    dataSource = GdprDataSourceImpl(
      httpClient: mockHttpClient,
      baseUrl: '',
    );
  });

  group('post Gdpr', () {
    const status = true;
    final url = Uri.parse('/gdpr/consent');

    const body = {
      'status': status,
    };

    final errorMessage = fixture('error_response.json');
    
    test('should perform a POST request to /auth/otp', () async {
      when(mockHttpClient.post(url, body: body)).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => http.Response('', 201),
      );

      await dataSource.postGdpr(status: status);

      verify(mockHttpClient.post(url, body: body));
    });
  });
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:
**type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future' in type cast**

Mocks have been successfully generated with the build runner

I also tried updating the mocked class and change the return value to

```
returnValue: Future<http.Response?>
```

I get: **type 'Future<Response?>' is not a subtype of type 'Future' in type cast**

Comment: What is the stack trace from the error?  Which line is it referring to?  Are you sure that there isn't a method on the `http.Client` that you neglected to stub?  Are you sure that you created a stub with the correct arguments? (The `Uri` looks wrong.) Also, is there a reason why you're generating a mock `http.Client` yourself instead of using the [`MockClient` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) provided by `package:http`?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I switech to using the MockClient class by package:http
and now I'm getting as error
Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was to use the MockClient class provided by package:http,
and not use mockito.

```
  group('post Gdpr success', () {
    Future<http.Response> requestHandler(http.Request request) async {
      final apiResponse = fixture('gdpr_response.json');
      return http.Response(apiResponse, 201);
    }

    setUp(() {
      mockHttpClient = MockClient(requestHandler);

      dataSource = GdprDataSourceImpl(
        httpClient: mockHttpClient,
        baseUrl: '',
      );
    });

    test('should perform a POST request to /gdpr/consent', () async {
      final result = await dataSource.postGdpr(status: status);
      expect(result, gdprResponse);
    });
  });
```