# Flutter Test Error - type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking

I am trying to create a simple test but I keep getting this error.

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  group('signin', () {
    final client = MockClient();
    final api = AuthApi('https://baseUrl', client);
    final credential = Credential(
      email: 'test@test.com',
      type: AuthType.email,
      password: 'pass',
    );

    test('should return error when status code is not 200', () async {
      registerFallbackValue(Uri.parse(''));

      when(() => client.post(any(), body: {}))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{}', 404));

      final result = await api.signIn(credential);

      expect(result, isA<ErrorResult>());
    });
  });
}
```

**Error is at line**

> final result = await api.signIn(credential); expect(result,
> isA());

If I remove those lines I don't see the error.

auth_api.dart

```
class AuthApi implements IAuthApi {
  AuthApi(this.baseUrl, this._client);

  final http.Client _client;
  String baseUrl;

  @override
  Future<Result<String>> signIn(Credential credential) async {
    final endpoint = Uri.parse(baseUrl + '/auth/signin');
    return await _postCredential(endpoint, credential);
  }

  @override
  Future<Result<String>> signUp(Credential credential) async {
    final endpoint = Uri.parse(baseUrl + '/auth/signup');
    return await _postCredential(endpoint, credential);
  }

  Future<Result<String>> _postCredential(
    Uri endpoint,
    Credential credential,
  ) async {
    final response =
        await _client.post(endpoint, body: Mapper.toJson(credential));
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      return Result.error('Server Error');
    }
    var json = jsonDecode(response.body);

    return json['auth_token'] != null
        ? Result.value(json['auth_token'])
        : Result.error(json['message']);
  }
}
```

I checked other similar question answers also but none of them worked. I am using mocktail package & http for post.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `package:mocktail`, but in general you'd get this kind of error if you neglected to stub everything you need to.  Additionally, method/function stubs expect *exact* arguments, so if your stub is called with arguments different from what you registered (i.e., `client.post` is called with `body` that is *not* an empty `Map`), then your stub will not be invoked.  Why are you even trying to create your own mock `http.Client` instead of using the [`MockClient` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) provided by `package:http`?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71381940/, which sounds like the same problem with `package:mockito`.

Comment: @jamesdlin tried MockClient from package:http but still getting type 'Null' is not a subtype of type

Comment: What is your stacktrace?  Are you sure that the error is still coming from the same line?  As I said, that kind of error usually indicates that you're invoking a non-existent stub, but `package:http`'s `MockClient` class provides stub implementations for you.  It sounds like either you're calling a non-existent stub on a different mock or you aren't actually using `package:http`'s `MockClient`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in that line:

```
when(() => client.post(any(), body: {}))
  .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{}', 404));
```

It means that when there's a `client.post()` method invoked with `any()` URL and a specific empty body `{}`, then it should return a mocked response.

What you want is to return a mocked response when there's any URL and **any body**, so it should be like this:

```
when(() => client.post(any(), body: any(named: 'body')))
  .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{}', 404));
```

However, if you want to test if a specific error is thrown, that code should be modified:

```
test('should return error when status code is not 200', () async {

  when(() => client.post(any(), body: any(named: 'body')))
    .thenThrow(ErrorResult(Exception()));

  expect(() async => await api.signIn(credential),
    throwsA(isA<ErrorResult>()));
});
```

First, you specify that calling API should throw an error (`when(...).thenThrow(...)`) and then you check if an error was thrown (`expect(..., throwsA(...))`)