# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

I'm having an issue Flutter unit tests and I've been running into this error for about two days now. I'm trying to write a test for an API call, Best practice demands that the response should be mocked and not actually retrieved from the internet. I'm using Mockito to mock the API response but keep getting the error below.

`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>' test/auth_test.dart 14:7   MockClient.get test/auth_test.dart 29:21  main.<fn>`

I've researched across multiple platforms to no avail, [This link has some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452160/flutter-test-error-type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futureresponse) but still did not help solve my problem. My research shows this error has to do with dart null safety. Any help will be greatly appreciated as I've been on this for two days now. Below is my test code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:chronicles/models/grace_model.dart';
import 'package:chronicles/repositories/auth.dart';
import 'package:chronicles/services/api_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

// Create a mock API service using Mockito
class MockApiService extends Mock implements ApiService {}

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

@GenerateMocks([http.Client])
void main() {
  GraceRepository graceRepository;
  test('should return GraceModel when API call is successful', () async {
    final mockClient = MockClient();
    when(mockClient.get(Uri.parse('https://www.thunderclient.com/welcome')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(
            '{ "message": "Welcome to Thunder Client", "createdBy": "Ranga Vadhineni", }',
            200));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this issue. Here are the steps i took.

Add build_runner package under dev dependencies

```
@GenerateMocks([GraceRepository])
void main() {
  MockGraceRepository mockGraceRepository = MockGraceRepository();
  test('should return GraceModel when API call is successful', () async {
    when(mockGraceRepository.getDetails()).thenAnswer((_) async => GraceModel(
        message: "message",
        about: "about",
        createdBy: "createdBy",
        launched: 2));
    final result = await mockGraceRepository.getDetails();
    verify(mockGraceRepository.getDetails()).called(1);
    expect(result, isA<GraceModel>());
  });
}
```

Ensure you add the annotation of that points to the class you wish to mock(@GenerateMocks([GraceRepository])).

Then run `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

After this, your tests should run successfully.